# Bottom margin collapse when i try to hide scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have 90% by 90% div inside my body and I am setting 5% margin in each side. When I try to to hide scroll bar using overflow: hidden the margin only looks like one or 2% .

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: silver;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top {
  width: 90%;
  min-height: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this?

```css
body {
  background-color: silver;
}

.top {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
```

Comment: my margin is collapsing which I don't want to collapse

Comment: would be helpful if you could put a screenshot to describe your expected output